# Building Term-Document Matrix with specific tokens (and all the rest)

Tags: r, tm

I'm trying to build a Term-Document Matrix that lists all the unigrams in a corpus but also extracts a specific list of bigrams.  So for example in the sentence, "use your turn signal" it would list out "use", "your", and "turn signal".

In the documentation, the sample tokenizer they provide is:

```
strsplit_space_tokenizer <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "[[:space:]]+"))
```

Any ideas on how to write a tokenizer that finds a given vector of bigrams and returns the rest as unigrams?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy. Basically you can pass over the text, find your bigrams and replace them with something that won't split on spaces (here i use "{0}" where the actual number is the index of the bigram in the list). Then i split the string, then I go through and replace the "{0}" values with the bigram value. For example, here a function that will build a tokenizer with a list of bigrams

```
getBigramTokenizer <- function(bigrams=character(0)) {
    force(bigrams)
    return(function(x) {
        x <- Reduce(function(a,b) 
            gsub(bigrams[b],paste0("{",b,"}"),a, fixed=T), 
            seq_along(bigrams), x)
        x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "[[:space:]]+"))
        m<-regexec("\\{(\\d+)\\}", x)
        i<-which(sapply(m, '[', 1) != -1)
        mi<-sapply(regmatches(x,m)[i], '[', 2)
        x[i]<-bigrams[as.numeric(mi)]
        x
     })
}
```

Now we can use it with

```
bigrams <- c("turn signal", "back seat", "buckle up")
tk <- getBigramTokenizer(bigrams)

tk("use your turn signal")
# [1] "use"         "your"        "turn signal"

tk("please buckle up in the back seat")
# [1] "please"    "buckle up" "in"        "the"       "back seat"
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I didn't think about identifying the bigrams before splitting up the string.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then qdap version 2.1.1 can help here as well:

```
library(tm)
library(qdap)

## the bigrams
bigrams <- c("turn signal", "back seat", "buckle up")

## fake data (MWE)
dat <- data.frame(docs=paste0("doc", 1:5), 
    state=c("use your turn signal",
        "please buckle up in the back seat",
        "buckle up for safety",
        "Sit in the back seat",
        "here it is"
    )
)

## make data into a Corpus
myCorp <- as.Corpus(dat$state, dat$docs)

myDF <- as.data.frame(myCorp)
f <- sub_holder(bigrams, myDF$text)
tdm <- as.tdm(f$output, myDF$docs)
rownames(tdm) <- f$unhold(rownames(tdm))
inspect(tdm)

##              Docs
## Terms         doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4 doc5
##   for            0    0    1    0    0
##   here           0    0    0    0    1
##   in             0    1    0    1    0
##   is             0    0    0    0    1
##   it             0    0    0    0    1
##   please         0    1    0    0    0
##   turn signal    1    0    0    0    0
##   back seat      0    1    0    1    0
##   buckle up      0    1    1    0    0
##   safety         0    0    1    0    0
##   sit            0    0    0    1    0
##   the            0    1    0    1    0
##   use            1    0    0    0    0
##   your           1    0    0    0    0
```